# How to plot several data points rendered from evaluating a function with newton's method

Tags: python, loops, math, graph, sage

I am attempting to gather several data points by using newton's method to approximate values of x^y=y^x when x does not equal y. I am having issues finding how to evaluate the function (via newton's method) at several different fixed values of y. After doing this I aim to store the resulting (x,y) coordinate points in a list and then plot them as a line. 
Here is some examples of the code I have put together so far.

(Please bear with my lack of coding skills, I've just begun learning to use sagemath, and my struggle to make this work has brought me here after hours of research. Thank you.)

```
x=var('x');
y = ? '''(Some varying list of numbers between 1 and 100 at increments of 0.1. 
I am not sure how represent this with code.)'''
f(x)=x^(y/x)
df=diff(f,x);
NewtonIt (x)=x-(f/df) (x);

#### this is the for loop I was playing around with
'''xn=1.5;
print xn;
for i in range(5):
xn=N(NewtonIt(xn),digits=20)
print xn;'''

#### this is the while loop that I am leaning towards using
x0=2; 
print x0
x1=N(NewtonIt(x0),digits=25)
print x1;
while abs (x0-x1)>10^(-25):
x0=x1
x1=N(NewtonIt(x0),digits=25)
print(x1);
```

I'm stuck at this point, I've researched how to store data, but to no avail. I found some basic code for plotting lines from data points, but I'm not sure how to store data points in a list then put said listed points into the line plotting function. I imagine the code for plotting the resulting line from a collection of data points would look like the code seen below.

```
line([(x0,y0),(x1,y1),....(xn,yn)], legend_label='Approximation of x^y=y^x');
```

I feel that the equation I have defined to be f(x) may not be the ideal one to use in solving this problem. Any insight on what to use instead would be appreciated, but my aim is to develop code that could loop through a few thousand iterations and create data points that could then be easily plotted on a 2D graph.

Any help or insight with this problem would be most appreciated. Also, I apologize for my fledgling understanding of sagemath and python, and hope that you consider this problem on my behalf.

Comment: Your code example, as you probably already realize is pretty far away from being executable in a fashion that get's to the heart of your question.  It means that someone attempting to help you here will have to go through an amount of work and correspondence that this site wasn't really meant for.  You probably need to start more in the basics of doing scientific programming in Python before you build up to tackle this question.  Have a look at numpy and scipy which have many root finding algorithms available

Comment: You can solve your equation directly by using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). In particular, you get `y = -x * sage.functions.log.Function_lambert_w(n, -log(x)/x) / log(x)` for `n=0` or `n=1`. See the [solution here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5Ey+%3D+y%5Ex+for+y) and sage's documentation [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/functions/sage/functions/log.html) (look for "Function_lambert_w"). Come back here if you try that and cannot succeed.

Answer (score 0):

The classic Newton's method from calculus is usually used with functions of one variable.  That is not what you are doing.  You should pick a specific `y`, and then use Newton's method to find a *zero* of some function.  In this case, `x^y-y^x` (for a constant y) might do. Here is an example of how you might get this to work in Sage.

```
var('y')
g(x) = x^y-y^x

def find_point(y):
    f = g.subs(y=y)
    fp = diff(f,x)
    NewtonIteration(x) = x - (f/fp)(x)
    x1 = 2
    x2 = N(NewtonIteration(x1))
    while abs(x2-x1) > 10^-10:
        x1 = x2
        x2 = N(NewtonIteration(x1))

    return (x1,y)

L = [2,3,4,5,6]
[find_point(l) for l in L]
```

You can then indeed just use `line()` with whatever list you made.  You could call it `M = [find_point(l) for l in L]` and do `line(M)`, for instance.  [Here is a similar live example.](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx9kM9qhDAQh--C7zA3J6Cueiy49FrY3RcoVdyauIGQSIxr8vad1mxZKDSn4eObP_ndB4tZyFiaTOgZtOC7UITOp0majFyAkHrsZyO1w8Be0gToCdKmclmvC4Y2sAhnoqMUAkXuI7vwzRn95rgdnDQ6LoACUBzEzPDh-Zp4E-uG6gv-aa1ZlLebVBwGWu6bgjAcoa66oq7idb8DffME_pu6a5a71Woglocf-EqfJvHT7Un0yPXY1tUjhRNNfG_KkujHTs7f5CkwxUAYCwqkhlN0lpvZUEnN8ZwrPlFzr4YrV20WzGphVsZljH0Bzm1sug==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Finally, it looks like you are using something from [this website](http://www.sfu.ca/~jtmulhol/calculus-applets/html/sagemath-cell-newtonsmethod.html) which happens to have superfluous semicolons.  You might like [this one](https://wiki.sagemath.org/interact/calculus#Newton.27s_Method) (which I just copied from), or [this one from the Sage wiki](https://wiki.sagemath.org/interact/calculus#Newton.27s_Method) better as models.